# web scraping using selenium and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to web-scrape grofer,and bigbasket information but i'm having trouble with the findAll() function. When i use  len(imgList), the length always return 0. It always show empty list  How to solve it?Can anyone help me with that? i get staus code 403 in grofer

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://grofers.com/cn/grocery-staples/cid/16'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\HP\data\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll('plp-product__name')
print(data)
```

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://grofers.com/cn/grocery-staples/cid/16')
response
content = response.content
data = BeautifulSoup(content,'html5lib')
read = data.findAll('plp-product__name ')
read```
````

in ouput i get:
`[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included

```
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\HP\data\chromedriver.exe')
```

Try

```
data = soup.select('div.plp-product__name ')
```

Or alternatively

```
data = soup.find_all("div",class_="plp-product__name")
```

Note the correct method is `find_all` not `findAll` as it was deprecated in the bs4 library.